# Как работает ~

Tags: логика, javascript, алгоритм

Я нашел два варианта поиска в строке:

```
"http://www.youtube.com/embed/8rwsuXHA7RA".indexOf("youtube.com") != -1
```

и

```
~"http://www.youtube.com/embed/8rwsuXHA7RA".indexOf("youtube.com")
```

Судя по [тесту](http://jsperf.com/parkovjkeee/6), второй вариант работает быстрее, но объясните, пожалуйста, как именно он работает.

Comment: так они разное делают... В первом случае вы получаете Boolean, а во втором число.

    ~"http://www.youtube.com/embed/8rwsuXHA7RA".indexOf("youtube.com")
    -12
    "http://www.youtube.com/embed/8rwsuXHA7RA".indexOf("youtube.com") != -1
    true

http://es5.javascript.ru/x11.html#x11.4.8

Вы и не используя ~ сможете indexOf вызывать.

Comment: Да, работают по разному. Вопрос как именно работает второй вариант

Comment: ну алгоритм в спецификации описан, непонятно, какой смысл их сравнивать, а ну понятно `~-1 === 0`

Comment: +1 ещё быстрее...
http://jsperf.com/parkovjkeee/8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`~` - Побитовое НЕ. [Пруф.](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D2%E8%EB%FC%E4%E0#.D0.A2.D0.B8.D0.BB.D1.8C.D0.B4.D0.B0_.D0.B2_.D0.B8.D0.BD.D1.84.D0.BE.D1.80.D0.BC.D0.B0.D1.82.D0.B8.D0.BA.D0.B5_.D0.B8_.D0.B2.D1.8B.D1.87.D0.B8.D1.81.D0.BB.D0.B8.D1.82.D0.B5.D0.BB.D1.8C.D0.BD.D0.BE.D0.B9_.D1.82.D0.B5.D1.85.D0.BD.D0.B8.D0.BA.D0.B5)
Преобразует входное число по формуле: `-(number + 1)`.
Т.е. 42 в -43, 789 в -790, -123 в 122, etc.

Comment: `-43````````

Comment: @eicto, да, абшибка, я никогда не юзал этот оператор, ибо остальных хватает с головой. Пока, во всяком случае.